# Do any languages use =/= for the inequality operator?

Tags: programming-languages, history, language-design, operators

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Not_equal) says:

> **Not equal**
>
> The symbol used to denote inequation — when items are not equal — is a slashed equals sign "≠" (Unicode 2260).
>
> Most programming languages, limiting themselves to the ASCII character set, use ~=, !=, /=, =/=, or <> to represent their boolean inequality operator.

All of these operators can be found in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Standard_relational_operators), apart from `=/=`. I can find this equals-slash-equals used as a way of [formatting ≠ in plaintext](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mathtext.htm) but not in any programming language.

Has `=/=` been used as the inequality operator in any programming language?

Comment: It might help if you explain why you care, what problem you're trying to solve. "any programming language" is a pretty wide field; it seems likely that there was *some* language somewhere in the history of computing that used =/=, but not so likely that a well-known language does. It'd be simple enough to *create* a language that accepts =/= for not equal, but I don't expect that'd help. So... why do you care, and how is this question constructive?

Comment: It's not used because not only does it require 3 characters instead of 2 (!=) it's also a really ugly way to represent the slashed equals sign.

Comment: Thanks for asking this... I was searching for `/=` in Haskell and just reading the meta description for this page told me what it was.

Comment: @BenBrocka "ugly" is of course subjective.  In the long list of attempts to approximate ≠ in ASCII, I'd argue `=/=` may be the clearest on first viewing - and among the most annoying to type forever after.  :) I vaguely recall some language that used `#`, which is also not in the Wikipedia table, so I wouldn't assume the latter to be exhaustive.

Comment: Ah, it was Modula-2; it recognizes `<>`, like the rest of the Pascal family, but also accepts `#`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is in Erlang. `=/=` means **exactly not equal to**, that would be somewhat equivalent to `!==`.

See more subtle differences (such as `=<` instead of `<=`) here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id198443

Comment: So all erlang code is sad `=<` `>=` everyone else's is happy `<=` `=>`

Answer (score 12):

In the long list of languages that don't use `=/=`, PROLOG uses `X =\= Y` as "the values `X` and `Y` are not equal", as opposed to the equality operator `=:=`. (Equality, not to be confused with the unification operator `=`!)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can define an operator with this name, same priority and associativity as !=, and add implementations corresponding to each implementation of != by calling the != operator.

Answer (score -2):

Erlang does.
The following lists all operators:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/erlang/erlang_operators.htm

Comment: I'm sorry: Erlang does use that operator, but your reference does not show that. The one from Artefact2 does: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id198443.